# AngularJS $location.path adding #!/ before url

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS `$location` to set the browser's url, like this:

```
$location.path("/post").search({
    id: post.id
});
```

but whenever I do the url gets set like `http://localhost:5000/#!/post?id=0` instead of `http://localhost:5000/post?id=0`

Is there any reason the `#!/` shows up?

Comment: did not my answer work

Comment: Your answer was helpful but only removed the ! from the url so it would read /#/post which wasn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app config you should use

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove this prefix, add this code to your config:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```